# How to get element property from array in Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have document structure like this in my `schools` collection
[image: MongoDB document]

I am searching school by its code from array of codes `School.findOne({ 'codes.code': '12345678' })` and I am getting my school but I also want to get `code.type` property from code object where my code is `12345678`. Should i use javascript `Array.find`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is selecting the matching array element by

```
School.find({ 'codes.code': '12345678' }, {"codes.$":1})
```

Otherwise, yes, you need to find the element in the array:

```
var myschool = School.find({ 'codes.code': '12345678' })[0]
myschool.codes.find(c => c.code == '12345678')
```